# How to add gradient between box and text in react native

Tags: react-native

In react native app I want to add gradient between box and text.

The image :

[image]

The expected image:

[image]

The code :

```
<View style={{backgroundGradientBottom: "#666666",width:Dimensions.get('window').width-30}}>
  <Text  numberOfLines={5} style={{fontSize: 20,marginBottom:15,marginTop:20,fontFamily:''}}>{firstParagraph}</Text>
<View style={ {justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center',  height: 300,  borderWidth: 2,marginBottom:15 }}>
 <Text   style={{fontSize: 20,marginBottom:15}}>Weiterlesen mit Tageblatt-Premium</Text>
 <Text   style={{textAlign: "center",fontSize: 16,marginBottom:15,marginTop:20}}>Jetzt 24 Stunden kostenlos und unverbindlich testen</Text>
 <View style = {{alignSelf: 'center',marginBottom:15,marginTop:20}}  >
  <Button style={{alignSelf: 'center',marginTop:10,backgroundColor: 'red',padding:15}}   >
   <Text style={{ color: 'white'}}>24 STUNDEN GRATIS-TEST</Text>
  </Button>
 </View>
<View
style={{
borderBottomColor: "black",
borderBottomWidth: 1,
alignSelf:'stretch',
marginHorizontal:15
}}
/>
<View style={{ marginHorizontal:15,alignSelf: 'flex-start',flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Text   style={{ fontSize: 14 }} >Bereits abonniert?</Text>
  <Text   style={{marginLeft:120,alignSelf: 'flex-end',fontSize: 14,textDecorationLine: 'underline' }} >Anmelden</Text>
</View>
</View>
   </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ['react-native-linear-gradient'](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient)

[This image shows what my implementation looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS1EU.png)

```
<View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
  <Text numberOfLines={5} style={{fontSize: 20,marginBottom:15,marginTop:20,fontFamily:''}}>
    In den USA leben auch zahireiche Luxemburger. Wir haben einigegefragt, ihre Sicht auf die Ereignisse mit den Tageblatt-Lesern zu teilen, Und auch hier sigt sich - die.
  </Text>
  <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', '#fff']} style={{position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}></LinearGradient>
</View>
```

Comment: Hi @TarifAljnidi,  Does this solution work for you? Anything, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

React native does not support gradient by default you need you need to use `react-native-linear-gradient`.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient